# How to see conversion value from SKAdNetwork in Facebook ad campaigns for iOS 14.5+ devices

Tags: ios, facebook-ads-api, skadnetwork

We are struggling to get post install events sent over to facebook using the SKAdNetwork route for iOS 14.5+ devices.

**Things we have done so far:**

- We have mapped the conversion value to the events in FB Event’s Manager.
- We have updated our app to follow the SKAdNetwork recommendations to call the `registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution()` and `updateConversionValue(_:)` methods.
- Using the `updateConversionValue(_:)` method we are passing the conversion value to the Apple.
- When we run install ads campaign, we do get install attribution for these campaigns.
- We do not use FBSDK into our app (mainly because of privacy concerns).

**My thought was that, once we inform Apple the conversion value, eventually apple should inform this to FB and we should be able to see this some where.**

However we are not able to see it or act on it. Only attribution we are getting is the install attribution.

I am unsure what else needs to be done? Would greatly appreciate any pointers on what could be the issue or where should I look. Thanks in advance